# Post navigation doesn't show (in custom template, custom post type, custom query)

Tags: custom-post-types, pagination, navigation, paginate-links

In a custom template,

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: News
 */
?>
```

I do this query:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'       => array( 'news' ),
    'post_status'     => array( 'publish' ),
    'posts_per_page'  => '2',
    'paged' => ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1,
);
$news_query = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $news_query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $news_query->have_posts() ) {
        $news_query->the_post(); ?>
          <?php get_template_part('templates/content', 'news'); ?>
    <?php }
}
wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
<?php the_posts_navigation(); ?>
```

But there are no `next` and `previous` navigation buttons. Why?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What theme you are using ? Is this any theme which comes with WordPress ? And please give the code for `the_posts_navigation` function.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'm developing my own theme based on Sage starter theme: https://roots.io/sage/ I thought that `the_posts_navigation` was a WP built in function. I'll try to locate it.

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_posts_navigation/